# Missing space in Android TextView when using setText()

Tags: android, ascii, textview

I'm writing an app that gets time from an ASCII clock server and displays it on the screen. When a button is clicked, an AsyncTask will run in the background to get the time. onProgressUpdate() will be constantly updating the time - the argument s is where the ASCII time is stored:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s) {
                // I had to use a StringBuilder here because otherwise
                // the real ASCII art won't be printed out
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for(String str : s){
                    builder.append(str);
                }
                String tmp = builder.toString();
                Log.i(TAG, tmp);
                textView.setText("Server returned time: \n" + tmp);
            }
```

The logged string looks fine:

[image]

But the output displayed on screen is missing a lot of spaces:

[image]

Not sure why this is happening because the same string passed to logcat is also set in TextView.

Comment: Who ever has given down vote must explain why !!

Comment: Have you try to use Html.fromHtml(temp) ?

Comment: when you try it on different  screen size,do you get the same output?

Comment: @Mohit yes, I did get the same output on different screen sizes.

Comment: @HareshChhelana I did. But it wiped off almost all the spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
setTypeface() would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a monospace font in your TextView.  The default variable width font will not make spaces the same width as $.

In the XML for your TextView, add this property:

```
android:typeface="monospace"
```

Comment: I just added this the monospace property but it didn't really change the output. There's still space missing.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't?  What did it do instead, and can you post a screenshot? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that its reducing your internal spaces by half,

eg - 8 to 4

because Java string consider each char as a unicode of 16 bit
you need to encode for 8 bit to display same output.

or try this

```
textView.setText(temp.replace(" ","  "));
```

or

try to replace space with **&nbsp ;**  on server

and use this for setText

```
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(temp));
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the server; but I did try fromHtml(), which didn't really work.